# Uploaded document get rename by sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload

My scenario: I uploaded some document on SharePoint online and notice that some file names were renamed,that is the file name start by "~$". Any explanation for that?

Comment: are you uploading the correct file ?
those filenames correspond to draft-temporal version of documents. they are created when you open your document on Office

Comment: You may upload the wrong files , if a file name begin with ~$ , it mean this is a temporary file . Or the file was corrupted when you uploaded , See try to repair the document and then upload to SPO site .

Comment: @Erin Yes am uploading the right files. if i have 500 files to upload it doesnt show any error when this happens. I can't go checking each single files,but is there a way to say migrate those files with the least error occuring